# MediaWIKI Changing write access for Mainpage to specific users

Tags: mediawiki, rights

Is it possible to to give access to some users on MediaWiki to allow them to modify the Wiki mainpage without giving them administrator rights in the User rights management ?
Which setting should be used ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit access to a specific set of users, you will need to install an access control extension. There is a whole list of them here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Page_specific_user_rights_extensions